# Why does my improvement request bar me from handling anyone else's?

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-examples

Why can't I handle an improvement request on an example if I made one myself—for something that I can't handle obviously?

e.g.

- first request asks for A
- my request asks for B (I made the request so obviously I can't handle that part)

In that case, if I know about A, I should be able to handle that part separately—and eventually get the reward for it.

Answer (score 22):

> I made the request so obviously I can't handle that part

... why not? As far as I'm concerned, an improvement request is just a todo list. And there's no reason why you can't decide *later* to take the time that you couldn't take before.

I see no reason not to allow users to satisfy improvement requests all they want.

Just stop giving them rep for it.

Comment: True; that's just not the problem at hand though.

Comment: If you're allowed to answer your own questions, you ought to be able to handle your own improvement requests.