# Let me edit my own improvement request

Tags: feature-request, documentation

I am not allowed to do any of the following:

- edit my improvement request
- dismiss my improvement request to submit a new one
- add an additional improvement request

Please make one or more of these options available. I frequently jot down something as an improvement request and then think of something more to add to it, but cannot do so.

---

Here are some (maybe?) examples. I can't pin down cases where I did a create-retract-create thing, since many of the links to my [earlier requests](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191259/frank?tab=documentation) don't show the text, presumably because I retracted them (?).

- **Multiple missing examples in a topic**. I sometimes think of an example that should be included and then think of another. [Here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/1383/set-operations#t=201608191311237020916) where I have multiple examples requested. Another issue with posting a request with for multiple examples is that someone might partially address it. At least for this type of request, it might be nice to let individuals post mutliple improvements and for the improvements to all be separately dismissed/satisfied.

  [Here's another one](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/improvement-requests/view/849), though the solution here was not "add all these examples" but instead "make a Docs area for the tag".
- **Multiple pieces of feedback on an example.** [Here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/849/data-table/7425/main-differences-from-data-frame-syntax#t=201608191321152891029) where I have several issues with or ideas about an example, lumped together into one request.
- **No-longer-relevant feedback on a topic.** Yesterday, I [fulfilled](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/86477) my own two-day-old request to split up a topic. It was a complicated operation and I accidentally failed to indicate that I was handling/addressing that request. I should be able to dismiss it myself now, I think. (This is just a create-retract, not create-retract-create, of course.)
- **Refining ideas for how to split a topic.** (Same link as the last bullet.) I might request "let's divide it into X, Y and Z" and then, after discussion with people on chat or further browsing of Docs, "No, better to divide it only into A and B". I'd like to update my request in a case like this. Of course, I could have made a vague request from the get-go, like "Let's divide this", but no one is likely to take that up, I imagine.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329351/how-to-replace-own-improvement-request-with-edit?rq=1

Comment: @KartikChughヅ The solution in that answer is out of date, thanks to: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329327/

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331982/248058

Answer (score 6):

I've been pondering the whole "dismiss own request with one vote still" thing. It's a little weird now because of how we create and group IRs for display. If yours is the only request of a given type, sure. Dismissing it yourself with one vote is easy. If it's grouped with an existing request (or several) of that type... then it's kind of weird - you vote to dismiss the entire group at once, but then your request goes away immediately while the others need another vote.

I'm also considering reworking how creating multiple requests of the same type works - right now we literally create multiple requests. I'd like to convert that to "upvotes" on an existing request of the same type. I hadn't considered the potential desire to edit comments... I'll think more on it.

Having said that, and unless I misunderstand what you mean by "jot down"... I'm not sure the way you're going about it is all that great. Improvement requests aren't meant to be a scratchpad for your off-hand thoughts. Try to flesh out your requests before submitting them - after all, someone might already be trying to handle them while you're thinking of ways to elaborate on what you had in mind.

Do you have any examples of your create-retract-create again workflow handy? Just the example or topic that you requested improvement on is fine, if you don't recall the exact text, etc. Thanks!

Comment: "Improvement requests aren't meant to be a scratchpad for your off-hand thoughts..." Exactly, one can not shoot in the dark, right?

Comment: Ok, I've added some examples. My thoughts are fleshed out when I jot/write them down, but they are not always final. I know that I did the create-retract-create loop several times back when it was possible, but can't be sure that it was on the topics I've linked... maybe I'm not looking in the right place for the records.

Comment: Looks like this is completed now. I see a "retract" option next to my IRs. Thanks!