# Dismissing my own improvement requests has the wrong effect

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

Here's the scenario.  I created an improvement request to move a couple of examples from one book to another.  After a few days of nobody else pick it up, I decided to do it myself.

Since I cannot "handle my own improvement requests", I decided to dismiss it.  After all, the work had been done to my satisfaction.  But the improvement request is still there on the example in its new topic / book.  I can't edit it. I can't "withdraw" it.  I can't comment on it to say that it is no longer needed.

Here's the example: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/design-patterns/1331/strategy-pattern/12362/using-java-8-functional-interfaces-to-implement-the-strategy-pattern#t=2016100807083352802

There are 2 bugs in the workflow, IMO.

- When someone "dismisses" their own request, this should be equivalent to withdrawing it.
- You should be able to implement your own topic and improvement requests ... but NOT get any bonus reputation points for doing that.  (Because that would be a rort!)

Comment: What the heck is doing a book on docs.se?

Comment: @Braiam - A "book" is the set of documentation associated with a "tag".  If there is a more acceptable term for that, please tell me.  (Or maybe I can ask a meta-question to discuss the fact that there isn't a good term for this ... yet.)

Comment: Afaik, its structured in tag>topics>example... and the UI agrees.

Comment: I think we just call that "the tag"?

Comment: Books have logically-ordered chapters (and sections and subsections).  That's entirely the wrong metaphor for Docs, which is intentionally disordered.  It is a bit strange to have _tag_ as the top of the hierarchy, though, given that tags are attributes of questions, not containers for them.  It might be interesting to discuss this in another question (or it might just attract bikeshedding).

Comment: I made a related feature request, "Let me edit my own improvement request" http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332722/

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom are you denying our will to bikeshed a meta question? What kind monster are you?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I know that is what "we" do. And it makes about as much sense (to an outsider) as referring to flaw in a computer program as a "bug".  I would argue that while there clear differences between SO documentation and conventional books, there are also clear similarities.  (Or at least, there would be if we didn't have severe quality control issues.)

Comment: @StephenC: _"it makes about as much sense (to an outsider) as referring to flaw in a computer program as a 'bug'."_ Nobody complains about the terminology "bug", which is one of the most entrenched and well-understood terms in the industry. So perhaps there's a lesson there.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these issues should be fixed as of earlier today.

It is now possible to handle your own improvement requests (this does not affect reputation, so there's not much point in blocking it), and you can retract your own requests with a binding vote.